# Joomla jquery how to load Joomla module

Tags: jquery, joomla, module

Is it possible to load a Joomla Module via JQuery?

in php I can do that with

```
<?php echo JModuleHelper::renderModule($module);?>
```

Now I would like to trigger this event by JQuery! Reason behind is, that I have to load the module dynamically.

Comment: No, you cannot load it via jQuery. jQuery is a javascript library which is a client side language. You can however use Ajax. Maybe if you explain exact the dynamics of what you're trying to achieve, a PHP solution could be used

Comment: I created a page with infinite scrolling, where additional content will be loaded dynamically. On the right side, I have space for banners. The first banner will on loading by the page it self. Therefore I built a module. With loading additional content by infinite scrolling, I need to reproduce more banners on the right side.

Comment: in addition: that means, the longer the page become, the more modules on the right side I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you would need to have a server side AJAX request handler available to render the content.  The article attached to the bottom is geared towards javascript, but could easily be converted to handle raw html.  First, you need a controller to handle the request.  In your components front end controllers create the file mycontroller.raw.php:

```
jimport( 'joomla.application.module.helper' );

class MyControllerControllerMyView extends JControllerLegacy
{
    public function renderModule()
    {
        $type = $this->input->get('module_type');
        $name = $this->input->get('module_name');
        $style = $this->input->get('module_style', 'xhtml');
        $module = JModuleHelper::getModule($type, $name);
        echo JModuleHelper::renderModule($module, array('style' => $style));  
    }
 }
```

Then in the front-end root, add the following to your controller.php file inside the display method:

```
$this->registerTask('myview.renderModule', 'renderModule');
```

Then the javascript to handle the request client side:

```
(function($) {
    function processAjaxRequest() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'index.php?option=com_mycomponent&task=myview.renderModule&format=raw',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: {module_type: 'MyModuleType', module_name: 'MyModuleName', module_style: 'xhtml' },
            success: function(r) {
                $('#my-side-column').append(r);
            }
         });
     }
 })(jQuery);
```

This all assumes you have a component you are developing to customize, but the reality is this cannot be accomplished without it.

Good luck!

*** EDIT ***

I edited the controller class name to reflect proper Joomla Syntax from MyComponent to MyComponentControllerMyView.  In addition, be sure to name this file mycomponent.raw.php when saving to controllers folder.

Comment: Thats a really good approach Brian. I struggle with the following problems. 1) When I adress the Ajax call with ...&format=raw, the mycontroller.raw.php wont be touched. If I do it without &format=raw then the mycontroller.php will be touched and the function will be executed. Which leads me further more to the second problem. The Ajax response of my call returns me not my module, instead I can see an additional view of my template.

Comment: @Perino the reason you get the whole template is without the &format=raw Joomla will render the entire webpage as a normal site visit.  I think the AJAX wasn't working with it because I had an error, I edited post to reflect changes.  If it still doesn't work can you confirm the file name for this controller and its location in your websites file system?

Comment: My Controller name is indeed mycomponentControllerMyView and it is located as the com_component/controllers/myview.raw.php. When I debug the session, the ajax call will not go to the first breakpoint in the myview.raw.php file. In the normal controller file, which has exactly the same content and is located in the same directory, the function will be get through! The only difference is the ajax call without &format=raw. What do i wrong? Additional question Brian, do I need the registerTask in the controller? I did it, according to your approach....

Comment: Try echoing out some test html without rendering the module to see if the code rendering module was the issue first.

Comment: Excellent Brian, everything will be fine right now. Because of several testings there was a small failure in my rendering statement. Thank you very much!